# PHP create multidimensional array in do-while loop from dynamically (user) generated queries

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, do-while

I need some help with my problem. I have administration for users where is possible create queries from actual database.

The user defines a request such as this:

```
["mysql_query"]=>array(3) {
    [0]=>string(29) "SELECT `order`.* FROM `order`"
    [1]=>string(92) "SELECT `order_product`.* FROM `order_product` WHERE `order_product`.`order_id` = {query0.id}"
    [2]=>string(121) "SELECT `order_product_option`.* FROM `order_product_option` WHERE `order_product_option`.`order_product_id` = {query1.id}"
}
```

Then I have function for processing queries:

```
function mysql_structure($mysql_key, $mysql_query = null)
{
    global $param, $mysql_output;

    ${'sql' . $mysql_key . 'db'} = (($mysql_query == null) ? $param['mysql_query'][$mysql_key] : $mysql_query);
    ${'query' . $mysql_key . 'db'} = get_query(${'sql' . $mysql_key . 'db'});
    ${'row' . $mysql_key . 'db'} = mysqli_fetch_assoc (${'query' . $mysql_key . 'db'});
    ${'total_rows' . $mysql_key . 'db'} = mysqli_num_rows (${'query' . $mysql_key . 'db'});

    if (${'total_rows' . $mysql_key . 'db'} > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            foreach (${'row' . $mysql_key . 'db'} as $field => $value)
            {
                $mysql_output['query' . $mysql_key][${'row' . $mysql_key . 'db'}['id']]["{$field}"] = "{$value}";
            }

            if ($param['mysql_query'][($mysql_key + 1)] != null)
            {
                $q = get_string_between($param['mysql_query'][($mysql_key + 1)], '{', '}');

                if ($q != null)
                {
                    $qe = explode ('.', $q);

                    $mysql_query = str_replace ('{' . $q . '}', ${'row' . $mysql_key . 'db'}[$qe[1]], $param['mysql_query'][($mysql_key + 1)]);
                }

                mysql_structure(($mysql_key + 1), $mysql_query);
            }

            unset ($mysql_query);
        }
        while (${'row' . $mysql_key . 'db'} = mysqli_fetch_assoc (${'query' . $mysql_key . 'db'}));
    }
}

mysql_structure(0);

$param['mysql_output'] = $mysql_output;

unset ($mysql_output);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump ($param['mysql_output']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output from this function is:

```
array {
    ["query0"]=>array {
        [8]=> array {
            ["id"]=>string(1) "8"
            ["cart_code"]=>string(10) "3nlc7x8ri3"
            ["order_code"]=>string(9) "201800010"
            ["user_id"]=>string(1) "1"
            //...
        }
        [10]=> array {
            ["id"]=>string(2) "10"
            ["cart_code"]=>string(10) "awzulr7bbm"
            ["order_code"]=>string(9) "201800012"
            ["user_id"]=>string(1) "27"
            //...
        }
    }
    ["query1"]=>array {
        [9]=>array {
            ["id"]=>string(1) "9"
            ["product_id"]=>string(1) "5"
            //...
        }
        [11]=>array {
            ["id"]=>string(1) "11"
            ["product_id"]=>string(1) "7"
            //...
        }
        [12]=>array {
            ["id"]=>string(1) "12"
            ["product_id"]=>string(1) "5"
            //...
        }
    }
    ["query2"]=>array {
        [1]=>array {
            ["id"]=>string(1) "1"
            ["option_title"]=>string(12) "title"
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

But I need create in that do-while loop multidimensional array like this:

```
array {
    ["query0"]=>array {
        [8]=> array {
            ["id"]=>string(1) "8"
            ["cart_code"]=>string(10) "3nlc7x8ri3"
            ["order_code"]=>string(9) "201800010"
            ["user_id"]=>string(1) "1"
            //...
            ["query1"]=>array {
                [9]=>array {
                    ["id"]=>string(1) "9"
                    ["product_id"]=>string(1) "5"
                    //...
                }
                [11]=>array {
                    ["id"]=>string(1) "11"
                    ["product_id"]=>string(1) "7"
                    //...
                    ["query2"]=>array {
                        [1]=>array {
                            ["id"]=>string(1) "1"
                            ["option_title"]=>string(12) "title"
                            //...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        [10]=> array {
            ["id"]=>string(2) "10"
            ["cart_code"]=>string(10) "awzulr7bbm"
            ["order_code"]=>string(9) "201800012"
            ["user_id"]=>string(1) "27"
            //...
            ["query1"]=>array {
                [12]=>array {
                    ["id"]=>string(1) "12"
                    ["product_id"]=>string(1) "5"
                    //...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are keys because this function works. Output is different, but format is what i need.

```
function mysql_structure($mysql_key, $mysql_query = null) {
    global $param;

    $sql = (($mysql_query == null) ? $param['mysql_query'][$mysql_key] : $mysql_query);
    $query = get_query($sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($total_rows > 0) {
        do {
            unset ($temp);
            foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
                $temp["{$field}"] = "{$value}";
            }

            $mysql_output[] = $temp;

            if ($param['mysql_query'][($mysql_key + 1)] != null) {
                $q = get_string_between($param['mysql_query'][($mysql_key + 1)], '{', '}');

                if ($q != null) {
                    $qe = explode ('.', $q);
                    $mysql_query = str_replace ('{' . $q . '}', $row[$qe[1]], $param['mysql_query'][($mysql_key + 1)]);
                }

                $mysql_output[] = mysql_structure(($mysql_key + 1), $mysql_query);
            }
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query));
    }
    return @array_filter ($mysql_output);
}

$param['mysql_output'] = mysql_structure(0);
```

I can also advise with this..